# FLV player totally contained in swf... no external files other than the FLV

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I have a banner ad which contains an flv player. Due to size restrictions for banners at the site, I've found a player which I think will do the trick (chrometaphore). However, the site in question does not allow anything more than the actual swf for the ad, so I cannot include the com folder for the player and need to include all AS3 code in the swf file. I'm not a scripting genius, and wonder what it would take to include all the classes in the AS3 file contained in the swf. Is it possible? Does anyone know where I can find a VERY lightweight player whose entire code is contained in the fla?

[edit]: It just occurred to me that if the flv is on a remote server, could the com folder and files also be remote? Currently, the path for the com files looks like this:

`import com.chrometaphore.display.video.colibri.Colibri;
import flash.media.SoundTransform;`

What would that script look like if it was pointed to a remote com folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import statements do not load external files. They tell the compiler where to look for the source code when you publish the swf.
You should be good to go with one swf, and no com folder!

Comment: So are you saying that I can call com files from a remote location? If so, can you (or someone) give an example of what that would look like? Thanks!

Comment: No  - I am saying that com files are compiled into the swf when you publish it. They are not loaded by the swf when it runs.